# display each item in the array without using a loop

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i have this certain php function. But i cannot figured it out how to output this one. This is the question // Given an array, display each item in the array without using a loop. (Do not use built in functions to do this, like PHP's print_r; use a recursive function to implement) 
and this is the code

```
<?php
  function print_array(array $input)
  {
  }
?>
```

can someone share ideas on this? Any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a homework service. Nor is it a service for answering interview questions (the whole point of the interview is to determine if you're qualified -- if you need us to do it, you're not).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `implode`

```
$your_array = array("abc", "5", "xyz")

$text  = implode(" ", $your_array); // implode with space you can use any other on this place

echo $text;
```

**OUTPUT :** abc 5 xyz

**FUNCTION :**

```
function print_array($your_array)
{
   $text  = implode(" ", $your_array); // implode with space you can use any other on this place

    echo $text;
}
```

**Recusive Method :**

but only used when the key of the array is numeric starting with 0, 1, 2 ....

```
print_array($your_array);

function print_array($your_array, $index=0)
{   
    if(isset($your_array[$index]))
    {
        echo $your_array[$index]; 
        $index+=1;
        print_array($your_array, $index)
    }   
}
```

Comment: $your_array = array("a"=>"x1", "b"=>"x2", "c"=>"x3"); Does your code works when the array is like this!

Comment: but using the function print_array(array $input){ } on it...

Comment: `implode` is a built-in function?

Comment: @user3717576 put this code in your function

Comment: **Do not use built in functions**, **use a recursive function to implement**

Comment: can you edit your answer based on my function print_array(array $input)
  {
  } above?

Comment: ive tried your recursive method code but it has not output

Comment: method works with array of numeric index 0,1,2 ..